# initializing a global variable with a function

Tags: c++, static

To initialize for example a global std::map we can use a function that returns a built std::map and use std::move to avoid deep copying it :

```
map<string, int> CreateMap()
{
   map<string, int> m;
   // build m....
   return m;
}

map<string, int> g_mapMyMap = std::move(CreateMap());

int main()
{
//...
}
```

I want to know if this initialization and the call to CreateMap occur before main() or just after main() ? Otherwise, I heard we can't initialize static/global objects with non-const expressions does this apply only to the C language and not to C++ ?

Comment: It would be very easy to test this.  You could print in the `CreateMap` function and print in `main` and see what prints first.

Comment: What you heard only applies to C.

Comment: Also note that unless a function returns by reference there is no reason to wrap it with `move`.

Comment: Why not make the function return a reference, declare  `m` as a local `static`, adjust the "build m" code to happen only once, and use the function instead of the global variable?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Brilliant idea.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tested it...  I thought that before main() there's only initializations and code couldn't be executed at this stage. Normally before main() functional code doesn't exist, isn't it ? Can you please give me more information about the subject ? I know that the program code is in the .text section, but there's a jump to main(), isn't it ?

Comment: As long as the code is the initialization of a global variable it will be executed.  You can't run arbitrary code but you can do some pretty complex initializations.